# Python, read and write file is cutting final output file to limited number of lines?

Tags: python, file

So I wrote a small script that will convert my g-code file commands by replacing "G01" to "G1" it is all working perfectly but these files are very big they can end up with more then 10 or 20k lines of code!
My problem is that file with all code converted ends up with 4715 lines but original file has 4817 lines. Funny thing is the for loop is going through all lines but only first 4715 are written(I checked that by simple a = a + 1 every time something is written to a file)!

Here is the code it is very simple!

```
import string
a = 0
b = 0
s = open("test.gcode","r+")
replaced = open("test_replaced.gcode","a")

for line in s.readlines():

    if "G01" in line:
        replaced.write(line.replace("G01", "G1" ))
        print ("G01 ==> G1")
        a = a + 1
    elif "G00" in line:
        replaced.write(line.replace("G00", "G0" ))
        print ("G00 ==> G0")
        a = a + 1
    else:
        replaced.write(line.replace("******", "**" ))
        print ("***")
        a = a + 1

b = b + 1

#replaced.write(line.replace("G01", "G1" ))
#replaced.write(line.replace("G00", "G0" ))



print ("Done! - " + str(a) + " number of operations done!")
print ("Loopcount: " + str(b))
s.close()
```

Comment: You should open files using `with`. Do you close `replaced`?

Comment: By the way, you can use `for line in s:` rather than `for line in s.readlines()`.  No need to create an extra list when you are just iterating through it anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment to  your question, you should probably replace your `open()` statements with `with` statements. So, your code would become.

```
...
with open("test.gcode","r+") as s:
    with open("test_replaced.gcode","a") as replaced:
        ...
print ("Done! - " + str(a) + " number of operations done!")
print ("Loopcount: " + str(b))
```

Please note that there is no longer a `close()` at the end of the script because the context manager (`with`) closes the file already.

All you code dealing with the files needs to be within the `with` blocks.

You can find more information about context managers [here](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example/).